# History data in CUBE

Tags: postgresql, data-warehouse, etl

Not sure if this is the right place to ask.

I am working on an ETL procedure that gathers the data about medication consumption and I have something like this:

```
Dim_Patient, the dimension for all the patients in the system
Dim_Doctor, all the doctors in the hospital
Dim_Medication, all the medications available
Dim_DateTime
F_Consumption:
    Id(PK)
    PatientId(FK)
    DoctorId(FK)
    MedicationId(FK)
    DateTimeId(FK)
    TreatmentId(DD)
    Quantity
    Current
```

Say that there was a record:

| ID | PatientId | DoctorId | MeditacionId | DateTimeId | TreatmentId | Quantity | Current |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 202105031250 | 1 | 10 | TRUE |

And that for any reason there was a mistake, say, in quantity, which has been noticed the next day. For example, there were not 10 units administered but 5. After the ETL, I would end up with something like this:

| ID | PatientId | DoctorId | MeditacionId | DateTimeId | TreatmentId | Quantity | Current |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 202105031250 | 1 | 10 | FALSE |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 202105041250 | 1 | 5 | TRUE |

How do you set up the `CUBE` with this data? The quantity here is clearly non-additive.

Given that I work with Postgres, I would have created a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` with `GROUP BY CUBE(...)`, filtering only `Current = TRUE`, but then I would lose track of history.

Do I even need to include historical data in the CUBE?

I am looking forward to hearing any thoughts on this.

Comment: This would just depend on what your use cases are and what you want your cube to represent. If you need historical data then you can't filter on `Current = TRUE` as you noted. Or you can make two Views if you need the data both ways. You could also add your `Quantity` field only on the rows that make sense to add, based on whatever your logic is, and treat the non-additive rows as 0s, with a `CASE` statement for example.

Comment: Thank you J.D. I observed that the majority of my problem originated from the fact that I was overwriting the DateTime FK. I resorted to doing role-playing dimensions for DateTime and introducing multiple dates. So, I now have `Created_DateTimeId` but also, `Updated_DateTimeId` and `Imported_DateTimeId`. So, I can now create multiple CUBEs with filtering `Current = TRUE` and target the DateTime I need for specific purpose...

Comment: Cool sounds like that should work!